# why hpacucli doesn't see my controller? "Error: No controllers detected."

Tags: debian, hp-proliant

On an HP DL120G7 with HP P410, per some [suggestion on a blog](http://geroldm.com/2011/11/install-hpacucli-in-debian/), I've installed the latest version of `hpacucli` from http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/ProLiantSupportPack/Debian/pool/non-free/ — [hpacucli_8.70-8.0.2-2_amd64.deb](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/ProLiantSupportPack/Debian/pool/non-free/hpacucli_8.70-8.0.2-2_amd64.deb) — but it doesn't seem to recognise my controller.  Why?

---

```
wget http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/ProLiantSupportPack/Debian/pool/non-free/hpacucli_8.70-8.0.2-2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i hpacucli_8.70-8.0.2-2_amd64.deb
apt-get install lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libc6-i386
dpkg -i hpacucli_8.70-8.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

…

```
root@sd-49XXX:~# hpacucli ctrl all show config

Error: No controllers detected.

root@sd-49XXX:~# lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    storage HP       P410             5.14  -
[0:0:0:1]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   5.14  /dev/sda
root@sd-49XXX:~#
```

---

*Is the latest version from the official HP web-site not actually the latest?*

Answer (score 4):

**Use this on repo**

> deb http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/ jessie/current non-free

apt-get update

apt-get install ssacli

run **ssacli** is the new version, same commands, i tested this with proxmox 5, the hpacucli didnt saw my HP H240, ssacli does and works ok

Comment: awesome! it works

Comment: tested working in "HPE Proliant DL380 Gen10". thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
"lsmod | grep sg"
```

if it is not there do:

```
"modprobe sg"
```

Then try utility after that.

Answer (score 2):

The working answer for debian jessie administrators, and mainly those who own **HP Proliant ML350 Gen9** is to use the command **hpssacli** . After searching the net for almost a whole day, I found [this page](https://github.com/glensc/nagios-plugin-check_raid/issues/114) saying that **hpacucli** is not working; whereas, the **hpssacli** works and shows all your needs.
I have **HP SmartArray P440ar** installed on my server.
Inshalla, God's willing that's, I will make a Webmin module for **hpssacli** and a Tcl/Tk frontend for it, just to ease the administration

Comment: why my answer is set -1?!

Comment: This answer worked for me ---- so I put you back to zero. Probably the person's hardware was too old, but it worked for me.

Comment: You are welcome. here is my Webmin module. [http://www.superlinux.net/downloads/hpsmartarray.wbm.gz](http://www.superlinux.net/downloads/hpsmartarray.wbm.gz)
If You are worried that it might contain evil code, just rename the file extension to tar.gz, and extract the file to get the file index.cgi. the code inside is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://web.archive.org/web/20121113093746/http://blog.wpkg.org/2012/03/15/hpacucli-error-no-controllers-detected-with-hpsa-module-in-use/#comment-6412, the following seems to do the trick.

```
wget http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/proliantsupportpack/SuSE/11.2/x86_64/9.10/hpacucli-9.10-22.0.x86_64.rpm
apt-get install alien
alien hpacucli-9.10-22.0.x86_64.rpm
dpkg -i hpacucli_9.10-23_amd64.deb
```

…

```
root@sd-49XXX:~# hpacucli ctrl all show status

Smart Array P410 in Slot 1
   Controller Status: OK
   Cache Status: OK
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
```

---

Apparently, HP doesn't supply newer `hpacucli` for Debian, but does for SuSE.

Comment: Newer HP utilities (including hpacucli 9.40) for Debian can be found at: `deb http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/ManagementComponentPack/debian/ wheezy/current non-free`. Unfortunately even this version doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

ProliantSupportPack is obsolete at least for Debian.

HP drivers should be in stock kernel, utilities can be downloaded from "Management Component Pack". To use it, add this list to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`deb http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/ManagementComponentPack/debian/ wheezy/current non-free`

However on my G7 server with SmartArray P410i even the latest hpacucli 9.40 doesn't work.